# HTML/JS/D3.js: Mouseover lagging in certain parts of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, mouseover, onmouseover

I have recently started experimenting with D3.js to create HTML/JS-based interactive figures. In my latest experiment, I want to create a figure which shifts a function along the x axis depending on where the mouse currently hovers.

My current draft works quite well in principle, but the behavior of the resulting figure is odd. If the mouse hovers over the main canvas (the area inside the graph), the updating slows to the point of near non-functionality. However, when you instead move the mouse horizontally beneath the x axis (across the x tick labels), the code runs as smooth as expected.

I am at a loss as to what might cause this difference in lag. Do you have a suggestion as to what might cause this?

To reproduce what I report here, run the code snippet below, then move the mouse over the resulting graph. The code will barely respond within the rectangle spanned up by the x and y axis, but will respond smoothly when moving the mouse below the x axis.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-hsv.v0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-contour.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
    
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_datavisualization">
  <svg id="click" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
          <g id="pointer" transform="scale(0.5)">
              <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="20" id="dragcircle" />
          </g>
      </defs>
  </svg>
</div>



  <body style='overflow:hidden'>
  
    
    <script>
    
        // Get the viewport height and width
      const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
      const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
      
      // Fit to viewport
      var height            = math.min([vw,vh])*0.7;
      var width             = math.min([vw,vh]);
      
      // Create the canvas. We will use only part of it for the main plot
      var svg = d3.select("#click") // This selects the div
          .attr("width", width) // This defines the canvas' width
          .attr("height", height) // This defines the canvas' height
      
      // Prepare the contour grid
      var conc          = linspace(0,60,101);
      var obs           = 24;
      var obs_sd        = 2;
      
      //print(conc_short)
      
      // Get the initial likelihood
      var likeli = likelihood(
        y       = conc,
        x       = obs,
        std     = obs_sd)
      
      var x_limits  = [0,60];
      var y_limits  = [0,d3.max(likeli)*1.2];
      
      // Get scaling functions for the x scale and the y_scale
      const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([x_limits[0],x_limits[1]])
        .range([width*0.05,width*0.95])
      const xScale_inverse = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([width*0.05,width*0.95])
        .range([x_limits[0],x_limits[1]])
      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([y_limits[0],y_limits[1]])
        .range([height*0.92,height*0.08])
        
      
      // Draw the x axis
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(height*0.92).toString()+")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
        .style("font-size", (16*width/600).toString()+"px")
      svg.append("text")             
          .attr("transform",
                "translate("+(width*0.625).toString()+","+(height*0.055).toString()+")")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("value of random variable x")
          .style("font-family", "arial")
          .style("font-size", (16*width/600).toString()+"px")
          
      
      // Draw the y axis
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+(width*0.05).toString()+",0)")
        .attr("id","mainxaxis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale))
        .style("font-size", (16*width/600).toString()+"px");
        //.call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(""));
      svg.append("text")             
          .attr("transform",
                "translate("+(width*0.95).toString()+","+(height*0.5).toString()+") rotate(270)")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("value of random variable y")
          .style("font-family", "arial")
          .style("font-size", (16*width/600).toString()+"px")
        
      // Get the data for the path
      var data  = [];
      for (i = 0; i < conc.length; i++) {
        data.push({
            x: conc[i],
            y: likeli[i]})
      }

      // Add a realization of the marker
      svg.append("use")
          .attr("href", "#pointer")
          .attr("x", xScale(24))
          .attr("y", yScale(0.2))
          .attr("fill", "blue") // "#c3e7f9"
          .attr("stroke-width", 5)
          .attr("id","point1");
      
      // Add the x coordinate tracker
      svg
        .append('line')
        .attr('x1', xScale(obs))
        .attr('y1', yScale(y_limits[0]))
        .attr('x2', xScale(obs))
        .attr('y2', yScale(y_limits[1]))
        .attr("stroke-width", 2*height/600)
        .attr("stroke", "#666666")
        .attr("id","vline");
        
      var valueline = d3.svg.line()
          .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
          .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });
      
      svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data))
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3*height/600)
        .attr("stroke", "#4794c1")
        .attr("id","thatline")
      
      
      // Shift the marker around on mouseover; restrict it to the contour
      var movex
      var movey

      svg
        .on("mouseover", function () {
            // Get the current mouseover coordinates
            movex = d3.event.x;
            movey = d3.event.y;

            if (movex < 0.05*width) {
            movex = 0.05*width;
          } else if (movex > width*0.95) {
            movex = width*0.95;
          }
            if (movey > 0.95*height) {
            movey = 0.95*height;
          } else if (movey < height*0.05) {
            movey = height*0.05;
          }
          // Shift the point to this position
            d3.select("#point1")
            .attr("x", movex)
            .attr("y", movey);
            d3.select("#vline")
            .attr("x1", movex)
            .attr("x2", movex)
            
          likeli = likelihood(
            y       = conc,
            x       = xScale_inverse(movex),
            std     = obs_sd)
            
          for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i].y = likeli[i]
          }
            
          // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
          // Make the changes
              d3.select("#thatline")   // change the line
                  .attr("d", valueline(data));
            
          });

      
      
     
      // ============================================================
      // Helper function: Printing function for troubleshooting
      // ============================================================
      function print(value) {
        var precision = 14;
        document.write(math.format(value, precision) + '<br>');
      }
      
      // ============================================================
      // Helper function: Linspace
      // ============================================================
      function linspace(start,end,resolution) {
        var spacing = [];
        // Go through a for-loop
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
            spacing.push(start + (end-start)*i/(resolution-1))
        }
        return spacing; // The function returns the linspace between p1 and p2
      }
      
            // ============================================================
      // Helper function: likelihood
      // ============================================================
      function likelihood(y,x,std) {
      
        mean        = x;
        std         = std;
        
        // Create a dummy variable
        var result  = [];
        
        normalize = math.dotDivide(
          1,
          math.sqrt(
            math.dotMultiply(
              math.dotMultiply(
                2,
                math.PI),
              std)));
        
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i ++) {
        
          // Evaluate the first element of the Gaussian mixture

          expon         = math.exp(
            -math.dotDivide(
              math.pow(
                y[i]-mean,
                2),
              math.dotMultiply(
                2,
                math.pow(
                    std,
                  2))))
          temp  = math.dotMultiply(
            normalize,
            expon)

          result.push(temp)
          
        }
        

        return result
        
      }
      
  
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Replace `mouseover` with `mousemove`

Comment: Yeees that's the trick! Thank you so much!